# declare type with same keys but derived type using typescript generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

In an attempt to reduce boilerplate when writing my unit tests in Angular, I'd like to easily declare a new type based on an existing type using the power of typescript generics.

For instance, from a class like:

```js
class BaseClass {
    member1: number;
    member2: Observable<boolean>;
    get getter1(): Observable<string> {return null};
    method1(): void {};
}
```

I'd like to declare a "derived" type using this notation

```js
type FakeClass = Fake<BaseClass>;
```

which would correspond to this declaration

```js
interface FakeClass {
    member2: Subject<boolean>;
    getter1: Subject<string>;
}
```

In other words, `Fake<T>` should:

- keep only keys whose type is `Observable<any>`
- change the type from `Observable<U>` to `Subject<U>`

So far, I am able to keep the correct keys and to change the type from `Observable<U>` to `Subject<any>`

```js
type KeysWithTypesFlags<T, U> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends U ? key : never;
};
// KeysWithTypesFlags<SomeClass, Observable<any>> => interface {
//     member1: never;
//     member2: 'member2';
//     getter1: 'getter1';
//     method1: never;
// }

type KeysWithTypes<T, U> = KeysWithTypesFlags<T, U>[keyof T];
// KeysWithTypes<SomeClass, Observable<any>> => 'member2' | 'getter1'

type ObservableKeys<T> = KeysWithTypes<T, Observable<any>>;
// ObservableKeys<SomeClass> => 'member2' | 'getter1'

type Fake<T> = {
    [key in ObservableKeys<T>]: Subject<any>;
};
// Fake<SomeClass> => {
//     member2: Subject<any>;  // I'd like Subject<boolean>
//     getter1: Subject<any>;  // I'd like Subject<string>
// }
```

But I cannot figure out a way to keep the generic types from original Observables. To be really generic, it should work whatever the type of Observable (i.e. we cannot assume there are only Observable of boolean or strings like in the example)

Any idea on how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `infer` !
In a conditional type you can infer a generic type, like here with `Observable<infer T>`.

```js
type Fake<C> = {
    [K in KeysWithTypes<C, Observable<any>>]: C[K] extends Observable<infer T> ? Subject<T> : never;
}
```

See more: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types

Comment: Great, I owe you one. Exactly what I wanted